# How to handle stress and potential stress leave

Tags: human-resources, quitting, manager, stress, resignation

Looking for advice on how to approach the experts involved and how to eliminate stress factors.

How could one eliminate stress to avoid the situation of feeling the need to quit immediately due to it in the first place and how should one, in general, prioritize his approaching of experts, managers and HR if it can't be avoided?

Especially in the case when one has the feeling that HR takes the companies needs in front of yours.

Comment: Keep in mind you can use the "edit" button to change questions which are off topic to be on topic. This can be a good way to fix/improve questions to make them on topic instead of reposting them :)

Comment: @Jonast92 I don't know the convention on Workplace.SE, but on other SE sites, when you post a question you are going to post an answer to, it is nice to make it a community-wiki.

Comment: @Tyzoid Thanks for your point, I've never made a community wiki before, I'll read about it.

Comment: @Jonast92 Ah, I didn't know that changed. Carry on, soldier!

Comment: see also: [How to professionally ask for vacation because of extreme stress?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17934/how-to-professionally-ask-for-vacation-because-of-extreme-stress)

Comment: It is not just a "feeling" that HR takes the company's needs in front of yours, it is the reality-- always. DO NOT expect HR to have your interests in mind.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to mention a few ways to *avoid stress*, if you fix the source of your problems then you can avoid quitting:

- Read Dale Carnegie's book [How to stop worrying and start living](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671733354) (It's awesome).
- Go to a massage therapist, it helps you to relax and once more relaxed it's easier to eliminate stress.
- Prioritize and accept that not all things can be accomplished, but you can sure as hell do everything in your power to do the important things first and only think of those things until the less important things come at hand. One thing at a time and you'll accomplish more than you ever would have while being worried ! :)
- Exercise and change your diet. It's amazing how much energy it gives you which enables you to work even harder but yet it gives you a certain amount of releaf from your duties while exercising which is healthy and good to avoid stress.
- Cut out caffeine, I've heard of cases (managers) who have cut out caffeine and it has amazing power after about a week of not-using, it gives your body a better chance to rest when you actually need it and so fourth.
- Seek the help of a herbalist (I don't really believe in it myself but for some it helps).
- Take a vacation, with no emails and no cellphones.
- Study the interesting methodology of [Mindfulness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindfulness).
- Eliminate other stress factors out of your live that you do not have any control over (people, activities, etc).
- Take short breaks throughout the work day, especially when you've hit roadblocks and need to take a step back.

  - Your employer may (check your employee handbook/with your manager) be fine with allowing a few minutes on your preferred social network site once in a while.
  - Take a quick snack break once or twice a day (preferably with a healthy snack: banana, apple, etc. see *change your diet* above)
- Keep a journal (or start blogging). Reflecting on how your day/week went on a regular basis will help you deal with stress as you get it.
- Talk to your boss. Maybe he is assigning you too much work or there is a mismatch of expectations. He should help you prioritize your work.

If that doesn't do it, consult a doctor and or a psychologist to determine whether you're able to actually work at all.

If you're not able to work then I'm certain that they can provide you a medical certificate or whatever it's called which gives you the opportunity to quit without finishing your stay-time. **Consult a lawyer** if the company won't accept it.

If they can't, then I simply recommend that you talk to the HR and or your manager (what's the worst thing that can happen, you want out anyway?) and ask them to shorten your resignation-work-duration and you'll do what you can to ease your leave.

If neither option is doable, then I'd recommend that you simply resign and work those last months and try to take it easy (along with my advice).

The last option is to simply quit and don't show up again, but that would burn every bridge there is and you'd have a risk of being sued, so **I advice you not to**. Again, if you want out but you don't know how, **hire a lawyer**.

Comment: `Cut out caffeine` - hmm, this one is interesting. I'm leaning towards the idea, but it's *so hard* to cut out coffe

Comment: @Adel It is indeed! But once it's out of your system it can be very helpful, I am myself simply missing the will to cut it out but if stress were a bigger factor in my life then I'd strongly consider it.

Comment: No coffee?  Geez, without coffee I'd likely just go catatonic for a month.

Comment: You can always reduce it or switch to other caffeine sources.  I've switched to mostly tea and it's helped a lot with digestion, not that I don't still enjoy a good cup of coffee sometimes, especially on the weekends, but it can just be brutal on a short night's sleep poured onto an empty stomach.

Comment: I can personally attest to ```cut out caffeine```. I used to drink 3-4 energy drinks every morning, but last year I slowly started to phase them out. Now I get significantly better sleep, I wake up much better, and my morning mood has also been greatly improved. There are of course other factors, but even now I feel significantly better than when I was gulping up enormous amounts of caffeine.